# Why are all my wordpress pages redirecting to home?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a page call inventaires, the permalink is mywebsite.com/inventaires
Whenever I try to reach it I am redirected to the homepage mywebsite.com

My htc access is as follow :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does somebody know what's wrong ?

My solution :

Clear cache of the browser. It was using a wrong cached version. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
```

try this code

Comment: Hello Nilesh; no success with your code.

However I've notice something wierd. When my permalinks are set to "simple" in wordpress, I can access the page. I'll dig into it.

Comment: please share your website link

Comment: Hey I'll edit my post. I forgot to clear cache after every attempt and browser was using a previous version... Thanks still :p